# $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be $f(x,y) = x^{[y]}$. How can we define this function at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

For any $y \in \mathbb R$, let $[y]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $y$. Define $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be $f(x,y) = x^{[y]}$. 
Then there are four options from which any number of option can be correct.

But my question is how can we define this function at $(0,0)$?

Can anyone give any suggestion?

Edit:**  I know the function is not defined on whole $R^2$ . But This question was asked in a National Level Exam in India. That's why I had doubt in myself.**

Comment: $0^0$ is undefined but can be defined to equal 1 without the creation of a contradiction.

Comment: How do you define $f(0, -0.5)?$

Comment: Yea..I did not notice  that.. Do you think the question was wrong?@mfl

Comment: I don't know what kind of function you want to define. So I can't say the questions is wrong. I only focused on a point where the definion of $f,$ as is its, gives problems. If you restrict the domain to $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ then the only problem is the definition at $(0,0).$

Comment: The usual notation for the floor of $y$ is $\lfloor y\rfloor$. Use `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`.

Comment: If this is exact wording of the problem then it is simply wrong. The question seems to have been asked by someone who doen't know the definition of  a function. You can give arbitrary values to $f$ at points where $x^{[y]}$ is not defined and  you will still get a well defined function.

Comment: .Yea this is the statement of the question and there were four options which I did not write. Sir this question was asked in  CSir NET  2018 June.  You can see the question here --http://csirhrdg.res.in/AnswerKeys.html @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: .Yea this is the statement of the question and there were four options which I did not write. Sir this question was asked in CSir NET 2018 June. You can see the question here --csirhrdg.res.in/AnswerKeys.html   (Booklet code C , question number 71 )@KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 2):

the problem should have included a value for $f(0,0)$. If $|y|<1$, then
$$
[y]=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}0 & \text{if }y\ge0,\\-1 &\text{if }y<0.\end{cases}
$$
Then, if $x\ne0$,
$$
x^{[y]}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }y\ge0,\\\dfrac{1}{x} &\text{if }y<0.\end{cases}
$$
$f$ cannot be defined at $(0,0)$ to make it continuous. However, answer 2 is correct.